# Maximize/Minimize Form With Two KeyDown Methods Not Working

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to get a WPF form to maximize or minimize when "enter" is pressed. However,when debugging, it doesn't work. 
 
 I can write this so that it can minimize but not maximize, but not be able to do both once one action is performed. 
 If someone could push me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated. 

 I'm currently using "Enter" as a placeholder for a combination of two keys that I haven't decided yet. May be annoying for some, I know, but it works for me at the moment.

 Also, I'm attempting to make a general overlay program that can run in the background and can pop up when the key combination is pressed.

```
private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
}
private void MainWindow_KeyDown2(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    {
         if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
         {
             this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
         } 
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that in `KeyDown2` the state is Maximized before you try to minimize it? Same thing for `KeyDow`. Try to add `|| this.WindowState == WindowsState.Normal` to the ifs

Comment: Just tried that, didn't work unfortunately. I specified in the form properties that the form opens as maximized, maybe if I try changing that?

Comment: Don't know how I didn't think about that, I'll look into that part. But currently, if the program begins as maximized, it does not minimize when "Enter" is pressed

Comment: What happens when you attach the debugger to the process, put breakpoints on those event handlers, and step through the code?

Comment: Thank you for trying at least. I'm not sure how else to do it from this approach, but I really want to get it working

Comment: @Adrian let me try that real fast

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this

```
private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{        
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
         if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
         {
             this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
         }
         else
         {
             this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if there's a different problem at work here, I think that having a single handler that toggles the `WindowState` is a better approach than two handlers whose call order you can't readily guarantee.

Comment: The program still doesn't maximize once it's minimized. Maybe it's just me and it may work for the OP.

Comment: @Adrian I agree, I took a very convoluted approach. Thank you Ivan, this worked perfectly for the maximization, now I just have to do something with hotkeys for it to read the KeyDown while minimized. At least I think so.... Guess I'll see

Comment: Minimisation might be a problem... I'm not so sure the program can receive keyboard input when it's minimised, due to minimisation removing its focus.

Comment: @Chipzilla I think it just won't read the key input when it's minimized

Comment: @kmartmvp To avoid a bad case of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) can you possibly explain in your original post _why_ you need the program to minimise/maximise on the press of a very commonly-used keyboard key?

Comment: It worked perfectly now with _this_ approach if you replace `Minimized` with `Normal`. I guess it's because the program isn't listening to KeyPressed events once it's minimized.

Answer (score 1):

Once minimized, the application will not raise or respond events such as KeyDown.

However, this works fine when it's in a normal or maximized view state:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
            {
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
            else
            {
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
        }
    }
```